# When was Martian Manhunter first depicted as a black man?

Tags: dc, martian-manhunter

When Martian Manhunter was first introduced in the 1950s, his human disguise was that of John Jones, a white detective. However, in several excellent depictions since then, he has been portrayed by black actors, including Carl Lumbly, David Harewood, and Harry Lennix. What was the first instance, in either animation or live-action, where Martian Manhunter was portrayed by a black actor? Is there any information in regards to why this became a trend when casting the character in other media?

Comment: [When Did The Martian Manhunter "Become" Black?](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/when-did-the-martian-manhunter-become-black.779216/)

Comment: I don't remember seeing J'onn being portrayed as a man of color in any comics (at least the ones that I've read). Therefore, IMO, the first depiction of J'onn as a black man would be DEO's Director Hank Henshaw in *CW's Supergirl*.

Comment: @Shreedhar Can't forget about Phil Morris on Smallville.

Answer (score 4):

In the comics, it appears that his first portrayal as a black man was when he was impersonating Bloodwynd as a member of the Justice League.

In live-action, it appears his first black appearance was in *Smallville S6:E8 Static* as portrayed by Phil Morris. Originally aired November 16, 2006.

I can't find an example in animation where he assumes a human form that is of a black individual. In *DCAU Justice League* when they go underground in *Starcrossed* three-part he is a white man. later in the Justice League Unlimited, when he takes a sabbatical from league business, he is an elderly Asian man. In *The Batman* as Detective John Jones he is a white man.